# check the lag for a Kafka consumer group

Tags: python, lag, consumer, group

Would appreciate help. I'm looking for a Python code that you can use to check the Consumer lag for a Kafka consumer group.

I want to use this code to check the difference between the latest message in a Kafka topic and the message that a consumer has processed. This lag can occur when the consumer is unable to keep up with the rate at which new messages are being produced and added to the topic.

The consumer lag can be calculated using the following formula:

Consumer lag = Latest offset in topic - Consumer offset

where:

Latest offset in topic is the offset of the latest message in the topic.
Consumer offset is the offset of the last message that the consumer has processed.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.